# Am I missing something with cin.get()?

Tags: c++

I'm learning `cin.get()` in C++ and I'm trying to echo two chars (including whitespace) back to the user.

While running the code, it doesn't echo out the inputs properly.

```
char letter1, letter2;

cout << "Enter Letters: ";
cin >> letter1 >> letter2;
cin.get(letter1);
cin.get(letter2);
cout << "letter1 is: " << letter1 << " end.\n";
cout << "letter2 is: " << letter2 << " end.\n";
```

I intend to input 2 and 3, however, it gives me a different result:

***Input*** (I had to type 3 twice for some reason)

```
Enter  Letters:2
3
3
```

***Output***

```
letter1 is:
end.
letter2 is: 3 end.
```

Comment: Why do you do **both** `cin >> letter1 >> letter2;` **and** `cin.get(letter1);
cin.get(letter2);`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that my intentions was to output whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

The formatted input operators skip leading whitespace (unless doing so is explicitly disabled, e.g., using `in >> std::noskipws;`). The unformatted input functions do not skip leading whitespace. As a result, the first use of `std::cin.get(letter1)` reads the newline character and the second use reads the entered digit.

You can explicitly skip leading whitespace, e.g.:

```
if ((std::cin >> std::ws).get(letter1)) {
    std::cout << “read ‘“ << letter1 << “‘\n”;
else {
    std::cout << “failed to read a character\n”;
}
```

The example also added some basic error handling: input should always be expected to fail and failures need to be handled appropriately. Obviously, failures need to be checked *after* the attempt to read input.